# Regex: how to find two letters that are repeating at least 3 number of times?

Tags: regex

For example, I would like to find `ty` in:

```
erytypotym5ty    
etytyty    
koetymitywty
```

or `il` in:

```
keililmil    
ilwrilltyil5ile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^.*(\w{2}).*\1.*\1.*$`.

The two letters (also digits and `_`; you could replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]`, if you don't want them) will be in group 1.

https://regex101.com/r/11Oq70/1

Comment: Thanks, it works and is even easy to modify with my little knowledge of regex :)